# TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got OrderedDict([('food', <FoodDetails: Nasi Goreng>), ('quantity', 2)])

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

I am trying to learn react and create a cart for my application
I have two urls one for ordered items and one for the order
in ordered items i store my multiple items and quantity
and finally store the ordered items as items in my order

here first i take ordereditems from my fooddetails url
and then use that array of items for my order
The food here is the id of ordered food, so that i can access its other properties if necessary

The data i am sending seems okay as but the items array is empty in backend after i send the data

```
    const orderedItems = await Promise.all(
      cartItems.map(async (item) => {
        const response = await fetch(
          "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/menu/fooddetails/" + item.id
        );
        const food = await response.json();
        const orderedItem: OrderedItem = {
          food: food.food_id,
          quantity: item.quantity,
        };
        return orderedItem;
      })
    );

    const order: IOrderData = {
      items: orderedItems,
      total_price: totalAmount,
      total_items: totalQuantity,
    };

    const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/order/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(order),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  };
```

This is my models.py and serializers.py

```
from menu.models import FoodDetails

class OrderedItem(models.Model):
    food = models.ForeignKey(FoodDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.food.food_name)
    
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderedItem)
    total_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total_items = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    order_status = models.CharField(default='Pending', max_length=255)
    ordered_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order_id)
```

```
class OrderedItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = OrderedItem
        fields = ('food', 'quantity')

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = OrderedItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('order_id', 'items', 'total_price', 'total_items', 'order_status', 'ordered_date', 'ordered_time')
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        items = validated_data.pop('items', [])
        print(items)
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for item in items:
            order.items.add(item)
        return order
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import OrderList, OrderDetail, OrderedItemList, OrderedItemDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path('order/', OrderList.as_view()),
    path('order/<int:pk>/', OrderDetail.as_view()),
    path('ordereditem/', OrderedItemList.as_view()),
    path('ordereditem/<int:pk>/', OrderedItemDetail.as_view()),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import OrderSerializer, OrderedItemSerializer
from .models import Order, OrderedItem


# Create your views here.

class OrderList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

class OrderDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    
class OrderedItemList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = OrderedItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderedItemSerializer

class OrderedItemDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = OrderedItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderedItemSerializer
```

fooddetails

models.py

```
class FoodDetails(models.Model):
    food_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(FoodCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category_id')
    food_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    food_price = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    food_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    food_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='food_images', blank=True, null=True)
    food_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Food Details"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.food_name
```

serializers.py

```
class FoodDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    food_image = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = FoodDetails
        fields = ('food_id','category_id', 'food_name', 'food_price', 'food_description', 'food_image', 'food_available')
```

views.py

```
class FoodDetailsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = FoodDetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FoodDetailsSerializer
    
class FoodDetailsDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = FoodDetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FoodDetailsSerializer
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('foodcategory/', FoodCategoryList.as_view()),
    path('foodcategory/<int:pk>/', FoodCategoryDetail.as_view()),
    path('fooddetails/', FoodDetailsList.as_view()),
    path('fooddetails/<int:pk>/', FoodDetailsDetail.as_view()),  
]
```

Comment: Look at the network tab in dev tools, does the request have the response you expect? If so, your backend code isn't relevant to the question. You may want to paste the JSON that's coming back into your question for context. Next put some console.logs inside your ordered items and see what's in item.

Comment: this is my response which is what i am expecting 
(2) [
0: {food: 11, quantity: 1}
1: {food: 8, quantity: 1}
]
and this is my ordered items 
Array [ 
0: Object { food: 11, quantity: 1 }
​
1: Object { food: 8, quantity: 1 }
]

here is a example of the data i want 
"items": [
            {
                "food": 12,
                "quantity": 5
            },
            {
                "food": 8,
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ],

Comment: Hit F12 to bring up dev tools and go to the network tab. Run your code and then click on your request, does the JSON match what you're expecting?

Comment: could you share urls and view

Comment: Yes it matches the JSON Data is as how i want  but the items array is empty when i check in backend.

Comment: If your POST has the correct data being sent then I would recommend reposting this question with only the backend code.

Comment: Show fooddetails url and view

Comment: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/menu/fooddetails/" + item.id look at this url. you want to use item.id but there is no id on taht item. If your orderedItem array is  [ 0: Object { food: 11, quantity: 1 } ​ 1: Object { food: 8, quantity: 1 } ] so there is no id field

Comment: the item.id is just taking id of the item and placing the number there it is working properly as 
Here is the console.log(item)
Object { id: 10, food_name: "Nasi Goreng", food_price: 40, food_image: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/food_images/Nasigoreng_sQsVEFA.webp", quantity: 1, totalAmount: 40 } 
the id here is the food_id for that food item